# is my iAds working?

Tags: iphone, iad

Ok so I implemented iAds into my current app.

Problem is how do I know its working as intended or not?

Debugging on local device or simulator shows the Test Advertisement, but also often shows nothing and the

```
"The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad inventory unavailable"
```

exception is thrown on FailedToReceiveAd.

So I set the iAd banner to hide if exception is thrown. And show if ad was succesfully loaded.

Anyway i did setup all the settings required  in IC and sent the app to appstore(update).

Now in my iAd module i can see the following data.. *se pic

[image: iAd Desc]

It does look right but when i ask some friends to check if the app is displaying ads ok they say the never see any ads.. I have seen some questions regarding this but only answers saying fill rating isnt up to quota or something equal to that.. What percentage do i have to reach for my ap to start displaying ads properly??

And is there a way for the app get out of that annoying exception that comes up way to often?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what the fill rate is. It isn't a quota that you need to reach. The fill rate is the percentage of requests for ads that result in an ad actually being served.

iAd's fill rates, as you've already heard, are pretty low, often less than 20%. What that means is that only one time out of five -- and probably less -- are you likely to see an ad. Worse, *most* countries don't have any inventory at all.

What can you do to increase the fill rate? Not a lot. Make sure you actually show the ad. Make sure it's visible for at least a few seconds.

You can increase the chance of actually displaying an ad by using something like AdWhirl, but chances are it won't be served by Apple in the case.

Comment: Ok, I must have misunderstood totally. This makes things clear.. Thank you!